# iOS lineChart View size getting small - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts, linechart

Here i am drawing a line chart  which contains dotted line and normal lines for that i am separating the values for dotted and straight line and placing in to an array of array.In some cases of values come the graph size is getting smaller than the chart view.

The third Party library I used is iOS Charts ,https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

```
for (_, GraphValue) in (param?.enumerated())! {
    var lineChartEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
    for items in GraphValue{
        let value = ChartDataEntry(x:(items.xValue!/60), y: items.yValue!)
        lineChartEntry.append(value)
    }

    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: lineChartEntry, label: "")
    line1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    line1.colors = [UIColor(red: 154/255, green: 42/255, blue: 16/255, alpha: 1)]
    line1.drawValuesEnabled = false
    line1.lineWidth = 2
    let graphValue = GraphValue[0]
    if (graphValue.isDottedLine){
        line1.lineDashLengths = [3,3]
    }
    line1.mode = .cubicBezier
    data.addDataSet(line1)
    chartview.data = data
}
```

Issue Image is attached here
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Hcg.jpg)

Comment: What is `GraphValue` and `ChartDataEntry`? If you use some third-party library, please introduce it.

Comment: it is a third party library for drawing chart , here i am placing the link of ios charts https://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

Comment: Can you maybe attach the values that are displayed in the wrong way? Also a screenshot of what is wrong would be great :)

Comment: @gebirgsbärbel : Issue image is added here kindly please go through it.